# My navigation bar refusing to center on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, web

Hi. I'm trying to build a website for a sushi restaurant with a responsive layout as practice to get better at HTML and CSS. I'm encountering a problem with mobile. I have a media query that changes the layout of the site for mobile. I'm working on the header, and I want to get the logo on top and the navigation under it, as opposed to having it all on one line on the computer version. I've gotten it to go on to a new line, but the navigation won't center. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
/* CSS Reset */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #CA3B1F;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* Navigation */

header {
    background-color: #35424a;
    min-height: 70px;
}
.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.highlight {
    color: orange;
}
.navlist li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.navlist li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 4em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
.current {
    color: orange;
}
.herobox {
    background: url(../Images/sushi.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.hboxhead {
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.hboxp {
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* Style the container with a rounded border, grey background and some padding and margin */

.box {
    border: 5px solid grey;
    background-color: #35424a;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px 0;
}
/* Clear floats after containers */

.box::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
/* Float images inside the container to the left. Add a right margin, and style the image as a circle */

.box img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10%;
}
/* Increase the font-size of a span element */

.box span {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
/* Add media queries for responsiveness. This will center both the text and the image inside the container */

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .box {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .box img {
        margin: auto;
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
}
.black {
    background-color: #191919;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
#whyus {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.line {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.margin {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}
.grey {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.price {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: white;
}
.left {
    margin-right: 60%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.sushipic {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.menu-icon {
    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
/* Media Queries */

@media(max-width: 888px) {
    .logo {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 15px;
    }
    header li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">Sushi<span class="highlight">Go</span></h1>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="menu.html" class="menu">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="home"><span class="current">Home</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="herobox">
    <h2 class="hboxhead">Providing top-notch sushi in Los Angeles.</h2>
    <p class="hboxp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SushiGo is a sushi restaurant in Los Angeles focused around
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;providing the customer with a premium experience.</p>
</section>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/Lauren.png" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Lauren Gerstmann.</span>
        <br> World Traveler</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">SushiGo is the best sushi restaurant I've ever been to! The moment I entered, I was greeted by the staff and immediately
        seated. I ordered at a very reasonable price, and the food came within 5 minutes. Everyone was nice, there were no
        problems, and the food was the best sushi I've ever had. Definitely going to come back!</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/daniel.jpg" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Daniel Radcliffe.</span>
        <br>Reporter for Food Insider</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">I'm supposed to list the pros and cons of a restaurant, but that's hard to do when there are no cons! Amazing restaurant!
        Thanks so much to SushiGo for doing what they do!</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/jerry.jpg" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Jerry Seinfeld.</span>
        <br>Successful food blogger</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">I am lost for words. I will literally only eat here from now on. SushiGo, you are the best restaurant I've even been
        to.</p>
</div>
<div class="black">
    <h2 id="whyus">Why <strong>SushiGo?</strong></h2>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="Images/lign.PNG" class="line">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="grey center margin">SushiGo has been working for countless years to provide our customers with amazing experiences. Here are a few specific
        things we do to make the SushiGo experience better.</p>
    <aside>
        <img src="Images/Sushi-chef.jpg" width="400" class="sushipic">
    </aside>
    <img src="Images/money.ico" alt="Cheap" id="cheap" width="60">
    <h3 class="grey price">The price</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has the lowest prices of any sushi restaurant in Los Angeles.</p>
    <br>
    <img src="Images/sushiicon.png" width="60">
    <h3 class="grey price">The food</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has repeatedly been reported by numerous foodies as having the best sushi in the US. We hire only the best chefs,
        and have high-quality ingredients.</p>
    <br>
    <img src="Images/experienceicon.png" width="65">
    <h3 class="grey price">The experience</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has been in business for over 50 years, and every chef has been making sushi for at least 20 years.</p>
    <h2 id="whyus">Our <strong>Allergy Policy</strong></h2>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="Images/lign.PNG" class="line">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="grey center margin">We want to make our restaurant accesible to everyone. If you have an allergy, please inform your server who will gladly
        assist you. All of our food has gluten free, vegetarian/vegan, and peanut free options, and we can adjust the recipes
        if necessary to meet your needs.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<footer>
    <br>
    <p class="center">&copy; 2017 by Sushi Go.</p>
    <p class="center grey">Website made by Sam Gerstmann.</p>
</footer>
```

The CSS media query at the bottom is where I'm having the problem. It is for the mobile site, and it is refusing to center the navigation. I'm sure it's a stupid error, I'm new to web development. Sorry!

Comment: Please post a **minimal** example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using media query make sure that you are using the same selectors as without media query such using `.navlist li` under instead of `header li` because it will not override,

I have done some margin enhancement as well, check the working snippet:

```css
/* CSS Reset */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #CA3B1F;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* Navigation */

header {
    background-color: #35424a;
    min-height: 70px;
}
.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.highlight {
    color: orange;
}
.navlist li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.navlist li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 4em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
.current {
    color: orange;
}
.herobox {
    background: url(../Images/sushi.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.hboxhead {
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.hboxp {
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* Style the container with a rounded border, grey background and some padding and margin */

.box {
    border: 5px solid grey;
    background-color: #35424a;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px 0;
}
/* Clear floats after containers */

.box::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
/* Float images inside the container to the left. Add a right margin, and style the image as a circle */

.box img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10%;
}
/* Increase the font-size of a span element */

.box span {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
/* Add media queries for responsiveness. This will center both the text and the image inside the container */

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .box {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .box img {
        margin: auto;
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
}
.black {
    background-color: #191919;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
#whyus {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.line {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.margin {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}
.grey {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.price {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: white;
}
.left {
    margin-right: 60%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.sushipic {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.menu-icon {
    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
/* Media Queries */

@media(max-width: 888px) {
    .logo {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .navlist li {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-right: 2em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    .navlist {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">Sushi<span class="highlight">Go</span></h1>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="menu.html" class="menu">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="home"><span class="current">Home</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="herobox">
    <h2 class="hboxhead">Providing top-notch sushi in Los Angeles.</h2>
    <p class="hboxp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SushiGo is a sushi restaurant in Los Angeles focused around
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;providing the customer with a premium experience.</p>
</section>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/Lauren.png" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Lauren Gerstmann.</span>
        <br> World Traveler</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">SushiGo is the best sushi restaurant I've ever been to! The moment I entered, I was greeted by the staff and immediately
        seated. I ordered at a very reasonable price, and the food came within 5 minutes. Everyone was nice, there were no
        problems, and the food was the best sushi I've ever had. Definitely going to come back!</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/daniel.jpg" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Daniel Radcliffe.</span>
        <br>Reporter for Food Insider</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">I'm supposed to list the pros and cons of a restaurant, but that's hard to do when there are no cons! Amazing restaurant!
        Thanks so much to SushiGo for doing what they do!</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="Images/jerry.jpg" alt="Picture of Lauren">
    <p><span>Jerry Seinfeld.</span>
        <br>Successful food blogger</p>
    <br>
    <p class="review">I am lost for words. I will literally only eat here from now on. SushiGo, you are the best restaurant I've even been
        to.</p>
</div>
<div class="black">
    <h2 id="whyus">Why <strong>SushiGo?</strong></h2>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="Images/lign.PNG" class="line">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="grey center margin">SushiGo has been working for countless years to provide our customers with amazing experiences. Here are a few specific
        things we do to make the SushiGo experience better.</p>
    <aside>
        <img src="Images/Sushi-chef.jpg" width="400" class="sushipic">
    </aside>
    <img src="Images/money.ico" alt="Cheap" id="cheap" width="60">
    <h3 class="grey price">The price</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has the lowest prices of any sushi restaurant in Los Angeles.</p>
    <br>
    <img src="Images/sushiicon.png" width="60">
    <h3 class="grey price">The food</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has repeatedly been reported by numerous foodies as having the best sushi in the US. We hire only the best chefs,
        and have high-quality ingredients.</p>
    <br>
    <img src="Images/experienceicon.png" width="65">
    <h3 class="grey price">The experience</h3>
    <p class="left">SushiGo has been in business for over 50 years, and every chef has been making sushi for at least 20 years.</p>
    <h2 id="whyus">Our <strong>Allergy Policy</strong></h2>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="Images/lign.PNG" class="line">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="grey center margin">We want to make our restaurant accesible to everyone. If you have an allergy, please inform your server who will gladly
        assist you. All of our food has gluten free, vegetarian/vegan, and peanut free options, and we can adjust the recipes
        if necessary to meet your needs.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<footer>
    <br>
    <p class="center">&copy; 2017 by Sushi Go.</p>
    <p class="center grey">Website made by Sam Gerstmann.</p>
</footer>
```